# Value of qudaratic equation

Tags: quadratics

In my exams, I was asked to calculate value of Quadratic Equation from given value of `a`, `b`, `c` & `x`.

I'm not good in mathematics. Does that refers to calculating roots of quadratic equation? As far as my knowledge is `x` is root of Quadratic equation that is already given.

Does value refers to result that we got after solving the equation?

Comment: Without more detail, it's hard to tell.  It could just be asking you to evaluate the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$.  Thus, if I said $\{a,b,c,x\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$ you could compute $1\times 4^2+2\times 4 +3=27$.

Comment: The quadratic function with the parameters $a,b$ and $c$ is $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. To calculate the required value you have to input the values of $a,b,c$ and $x$.

Comment: @callculus can you please post as a answer?

Comment: @AdnanUmer I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **general form** of a quadratic function is $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c$ are the parameters and $x$ the independent variable.

For given values of $a,b,c$ and $x$ the value of $f(x|a,b,c)$ can be calculated by putting in the corresponding values into the quadratic function.

Answer (score 0):

The general standard form of a quadratic equation is $ax^2+bx+c$.If you have $\{a,b,c,d\}$ know then you might just substitute the required values.